# Displaying enum in the console C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have an assignment, I have to get a date and then display it in different formats(MM/DD/YYYY, DD/MM/YYYY, DD of month YYYY and so on...). The months have to be enum and I have to make it in a separate class `Date`. I tried first turning the enum into strings with a `switch` but always when I parse the number from the console I get an error.
Here is the code:

> enum Month { January = 1, Fabruary, March, April, May, June, July,August, September, October,
> November, December }
>
> ```
> class Date
> {
>     private int m_Day, m_Year;
>     private Month m_Month;
>     
>     public Date(int day, Month month, int year)
>     {
>         this.m_Day = day;
>         this.m_Month = month;
>         this.m_Year = year;
>     }
>     public void Print()
>     {
>         string month = "";
>         Console.WriteLine(PrintMonth(month));
>     }
>     public string PrintMonth(string month)
>     {
>         int x = (int)Month;
>         switch (x)
>         {
>             case 1:
>                 month = "January";
>                 break;
>             case 2:
>                 month = "Fabruary";
>                 break;
>             case 3:
>                 month = "March";
>                 break;
>             case 4:
>                 month = "April";
>                 break;
>         }
>         return month;
>     }
>     public int Day
>     {
>         get { return m_Day; }
>         set { if(Day>=0&&Day<=31)m_Day = value; }
>     }
>     public Month Month
>     {
>         get { return m_Month; }
>         set { if (Month >= Month.January && Month <= Month.December)m_Month = value; }
>     }
>     public int Year
>     {
>         get { return m_Year; }
>         set { m_Year = value; }
>     }
> }
> ```

And that's the `Main` block

> static void Main(string[] args)
>
> ```
>   {
>         int m_Day=0, m_Year=0;
>         Month m_Month=0;
>         Date date = new Date(m_Day,m_Month,m_Year);
>         int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
>         m_Month = (Month)month;
>         date.PrintMonth(m_Month);
>     }
> ```

Comment: What is the error exactly? On which line?

Comment: It says that the error is on this line
`date.PrintMonth(m_Month);`

Comment: That method takes a `string`. You're giving it an `enum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to write the enum value:

```
enum Month
{
    January=1,
    February=2
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((Month)1));
}
```

So your PrintMonth can take an int or a Month value, a ToString() of an enum returns its string representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
  m_Month = (Month)month;
        date.PrintMonth(m_Month.ToString());
```

But its not proper way of implementation. You should be using Enum.Parse or Enum.TryParse and using (int)Enum to get integer value and Enum.ToString() to get the string value